# CSS Doesn't Change Text Color as Expected

Tags: html, css

In a page I have an HTML element

```
<span class="ysf-game-status ">
    <a class="F-reset" href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/miami-dolphins-washington-redskins-20150913028/" target="sports" onclick="pop(this)">Sun 10:00 am  @ Mia</a>
</span>
```

How would I change the text color of the `Sun 10:00 am @ Mia` text?

I tried

```
.ysf-game-status > .F-reset {
    color: blue;
}
```

but that did not work. However, I created a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8xqj24m/)** and it seems to work there. What am I doing wrong?

[Here](http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/326198/matchup?week=1&mid1=2&mid2=1) is a link to an example page I am trying to modify. I want to change the text below the player name to a different color.

Comment: You probably have other CSS rules that are more specific than that one and are overriding it.

Comment: if you have used their whole code, then that .F-reset has got higher specificity than the CSS they have given `#Stencil .F-reset {color:#333;}`  
[Read about Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: I have always had some issues with cache and CSS... Try clearing your browser cache or try another browser and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color is set by a rule with the selector `#Stencil .F-reset`. As this is more specific than the selector that you use, it takes precedence.

You need a selector that is as specific and comes after that rule, or a selector that is more specific. You can use the more specific selector:

```
#Stencil .ysf-game-status > .F-reset {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#Stencil .F-reset{
    color:blue;
}
```

The ID is more specific. Unless you target that, it is being overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work

```
#Stencil .F-reset {
    color:blue !important;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

Use just this:

```
.F-reset {
        color: blue;
    }
```

I think you dont need more than that. But if you use this class more than once and you want this specific just use like this :

```
 .F-reset {
        color: blue !impotant;
    }
```